# Existence criterion for solution in quadratic programming

Tags: convex-analysis, quadratic-programming

I have the problem

$$ \begin{align*}\min \quad&f(x)= c^Tx + x^TQx \\  &x\in D \end{align*}$$
with $D=\{ x \in \mathbb{R}^n \mid Ax \leq b\}$, $A,Q\in \mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$ and $b,c \in \mathbb{R}^n$ and $Q$ is positive definite which implies that f is stricly convex.

It is claimed [here on page 27 on the bottom](http://www.math.washington.edu/~rtr/fundamentals.pdf) that $f$ attains its minimum value, i.e. it exits a $x_0 \in D$ with $f(x_0) = \inf \{ f(x) \mid x\in D\}$ if $$D\neq \emptyset \quad\text{ and } \quad \inf \{ f(x) \mid x\in D\} \neq - \infty$$ holds. However, there is no proof given.

Can anyone tell me where I can find this proof or explain why this should be the case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $f^{*}$ be the infimum of $f$ on $D$ and consider a sequence $x_k$ such that 
$f(x_k)\to f^{*}$. Since $f$ is quadratic and its Hessian is positive definite, we have that $(x_k)$ is bounded. Indeed, if $\lambda>0$ is the smallest eigenvalue of $Q$, we have $f(x)\geq\lambda|x|^2-|c||x|$. So, $(x_k)$ has a convergent subsequence.
Let $x^{*}$ be the limit point of this subsequence. Then, $f(x^{*})=f^{*}$.

Comment: Welcome to math.stackexchange. You can learn how to type math symbols [here.](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)

Comment: Nice! After two years waiting finally a solid awesome answer! Thanks!

Comment: Wait - how do you know that $(x_k)$ is bounded? $f(x_k) \geq |x_k|$ is not enough right?

Comment: No. But we can conclude as follows. If we had an unbounded subsequence of (xk), say, xk \to \infty for some infinite set of indices, then we would have f(xk)>=|xk|(lbd|xk|-|c|)\to \infty.

Comment: I am happy to help. Best regards

Comment: @Ademir 

can you show how $$f(x)\geq\lambda|x|^2-|c||x|$$, I do not understand the last term $|c||x|$